# What is the difference Glide RequestOptions from Old Usage?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit, android-glide

I read that if we use Glide 4+ we have to use RequestOptions. But I'm not using RequestOptions and when I try to use RequestOptions nothing is changed. So what is the difference Glide RequestOptions from Old Usage. I look at Glide official site but I couldn't find main reason ? Also this is inside of onBindViewHolder() from RecyclerView Adapter. This is my code:

```
      Glide.with(context).load(ApiClient.Base_URL + imagesList.get(position).getImage())
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                                .dontAnimate()
                                .dontTransform()
                                .fitCenter()
                                .error(R.drawable.errorcircle128white)
                                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                        viewHolderSingle.postsSingleImageprogress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                        viewHolderSingle.postsSingleImageprogress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                })
                                .into(viewHolderSingle.postSingleImageView);
```